# Runtime Error in C++ 14 due to 2D array declaration

Tags: c++, c++14

Can you tell me why I am getting a run time error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define lld long long int
#define size 10000
using namespace std;
static int matrix[size][size];
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Do you get an error when size is much less than 10000?

Comment: There is no error when compiling by gcc with flag `-std=c++14`

Comment: unrelated, but don't use <stdio.h> is C++ program, use <cstdio>

Comment: 10000*10000*sizeof(int)  = 400 Megabytes,  which you try to reserve in static storage. It depends on your platform and implementation that such would be possible

Comment: `try{}catch()` please

Answer (score 0):

`int matrix[size][size];` uses automatic memory which you just run out of it because of `10000 * 10000` elements in your matrix. If you need such a big matrix you have to use dynamic memory or a container that uses dynamic memory e.g. `std::vector`:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(size, vector<int>(size, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot create an array with that size because of the memory size limitation of a 2D array.
Solution :

```
vector<pair<int , int>> matrix;
```